# Insert document type in XSLT

Tags: web-part, jquery

I have an XSLT that transforms a picture library and turns it into a jQuery galleria control. I can make it work in a standard html page, but I have the need to put it in a Sharepoint 2007 web-part, so the content type is not available:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
```

Is there a way I can assign this to the page using XSLT, Javascript or otherwise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure where the barrier is. You shouldn't need to change anything about the DOCTYPE for jQuery to work.

Have you looked at using a DVWP to set up the basic structure and then laying your jQuery on top of that? Or do you mean that you want to develop a Custom Web Part which contains the solution?